# Find where property of object in array is bigger than property in other object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I try to find documents where property **rate** in object is bigger than property **rate** in other object (both are in the same array)

Example document:

```json
{
  "rates": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "rate": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "rate": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how i tried:

```
db.ratesCollection.find({  
  $where: 
    {"rates": { $elemMatch: {name: "x", "rate"}}} > 
    {"rates": { $elemMatch: {name: "y", "rate"}}} 
}).pretty()
```

The problem is that I don't know how to compare values when firstly I need to find object in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` to process the array and fetch `x_rate` and `y_rate` first. After that compare the 2 values to get the result.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "x_rate": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$rates",
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.name",
                  "x"
                ]
              },
              "$$this.rate",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "y_rate": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$rates",
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.name",
                  "y"
                ]
              },
              "$$this.rate",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          "$x_rate",
          "$y_rate"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      x_rate: false,
      y_rate: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sRpRZvT_55P) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Query

- `x>y` <=> `x-y > 0`
- reduce to find the `x-y` and check if its bigger than 0
- initial `value=0` if we find `x` we add if we find `y` subtract, else keep value as it is

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70483669-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":
  {"$expr":
   {"$gt":
    [{"$reduce":
      {"input":"$rates",
       "initialValue":0,
       "in":
       {"$switch":
        {"branches":
         [{"case":{"$eq":["$$this.name", "x"]},
           "then":{"$add":["$$value", "$$this.rate"]}},
          {"case":{"$eq":["$$this.name", "y"]},
           "then":{"$subtract":["$$value", "$$this.rate"]}}],
         "default":"$$value"}}}},
     0]}}}])
```